Does $a_n^2 \geq a_n$ follow from $a_{n+1} \geq a_n^2+\frac{1}{5}$?
Let $(a_n)_{n \geq 0}$ be a sequence of real numbers such that
$a_{n+1} \geq a_n^2+\frac{1}{5}$ for all $n \geq0$.
Prove that $\sqrt{a_{n+5}} \geq a_{n-5}^2$, for all $n\geq5$.
This is a problem from "Putnam and Beyond". It is a given a sloution starting with "it sufficies to prove that $a_{n+5}\geq a_n^2$, for all $n \geq 0$".
But then, to go from $a_{n+5}\geq a_n^2$ to $a_{n+5}\geq a_{n-5}^4$ shouldn't we know that $a_n^2 \geq a_n$ (or $|a_n|\geq 1$) ?
How do we get to this conclusion, or what is it that I get wrong?

FYI, using an Approach0 search, there's the AoPS thread US Inequality. It also includes the AoPS threads Inequalities Marathon and Inequalities Marathon, but the links don't seem to go to the correct posts.

With
$$a_{n+5}\ge a_n^2$$
for all $n\ge 0$, then for all $n \ge 5$ we also have
$$a_n\ge a_{n-5}^2\;\;\to\;\;a_n^2\ge a_{n-5}^4$$
Combining the $2$ inequalities above, and using that $a_{n+5}$ must be non-negative as it's greater than or equal to a square, gives
$$a_{n+5}\ge a_{n-5}^4 \;\;\to\;\; \sqrt{a_{n+5}}\ge a_{n-5}^2$$
Note this doesn't require that $a_n^2 \geq a_n$ (or $|a_n|\geq 1$).
